# How to start fresh Chromium instance?

Tags: chromium, testing, cookie

I am testing web applications. I therefor always need a browser that does not have any cookies, saved logins, etc. Put shortly: a fresh instance.

As we just work with Chromium, I wonder how to start such an fresh instance.

I don't want to set up my regular Chromium installation to not save cookies and such. I want an extra instance.

Comment: You can create a new window in a temporary profile or use incognito mode.

Comment: @Salem Well, that would work.

Answer (score 5):

There is a flag in chromium, which when set starts Chromium with a temporary profile: `--temp-profile`

I have the following script that I use when I want a clean instance of chromium:

```
#!/bin/bash
chromium-browser --temp-profile $*
```

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to solve that problem:

1. Open a new window in Incognito mode (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>) (thanks to @Salem) for temporary usage
2. Create a new profile with `chromium-browser --user-data-dir=/new/directory`. In this new profile, you can switch off all cookies, plugins, etc. and restart it with the same command whenever you need it.

Comment: BTW those options can also be accessed with a right click on the Chromium launcher icon (with Unity).

Comment: Opening an incognito window does not *guarantee* a fresh instance.  Multiple simultaneous incognito windows will share a context.