# How to have two separate Chrome dock items

Tags: google-chrome, gnome-shell, .desktop, ubuntu-dock

I'm using <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> to access the first item on the dock/launcher, which is Google Chrome.

I want to have <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> bound to another instance of Chrome, so that I could go between them with my keyboard.

I have tried creating a dedicated chrome profile (Profile 4) and adding a `chrome-2.desktop` entry with the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Icon[en_US]=google-chrome
Exec=google-chrome --profile-directory=Profile\ 4
Name[en_US]=Chrome-Profile\ 4
Name=Chrome-Profile\ 4
Icon=google-chrome
```

Now I have 2 Chrome icons in *Applications*:
[image]

and I can indeed drag&drop the newly created Chrome to my launcher:
[image]

The problem is, when I click it, or do <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> in keyboard, it opens a new window but binds it to the first dock item, so I get two Chrome instances on the first item, and nothing on the second one:
[image]

What am I missing here? Is this even possible? I don't mind downloading anything the would be nice to solve it in a "clean" way.

**strong text**Things tried:
adding `StartupWmClass=Profile4` and `Exec=google-chrome --profile-directory=Profile\ 4 --class Profile4` as mentioned in the comments. the result is still opening the windows under the first chrome dock item, and displaying this:

[image]

Comment: Try adding a new custom `--class` and a corresponding `StartupWMClass` entry to the `chrome-2.desktop` file [following this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1054494/480481). It works with Firefox, not sure about Chrome.

Comment: thanks, tried that and it doesn't work (see image at bottom of question)

Comment: I can also confirm that chrome does not cooperate with the `StartupWMClass` tactic. You can also see what it does by using `wmctrl -l -x` to print out the `WM_CLASS` of all open windows at a command line. If you create two launcher icons for chrome, each with a different class, "the first one wins". If you click launcher A, then B, then both windows will have the custom `WM_CLASS` of A. If you then close all chrome windows and click launcher B, then A, then `wmctrl` shows the `WM_CLASS` of B for both.

Comment: halleluyah! this other answer (https://askubuntu.com/a/1113914/231504) is working for me. the key is their "step 3", which says: Add `--user-data-dir=...` to the Exec line, due to  https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=118613