# How to make .desktop file to open with its own icon in sidebar

Tags: launcher, .desktop, window-manager

I have created a .desktkop file to open GitHub using brave browser

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Name=GitHub
GenericName=GitHub
Comment=Github desktop app
Exec=/opt/brave.com/brave/brave-browser --profile-directory="Default" --app=https://github.com/
Icon=/home/parag/.icons/github-desktop.svg
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
MimeType=text/plain;
Categories=Network;Application;
Keywords=Github;gitapp;
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=Github
```

But the problem is that it comes as an instance of the browser with the browser icon in the sidebar.

[image]

I want it to show its own icon in the sidebar instead of the browser icon.

Is there any way to do it??

thanks in advance :))

**Edit 1**

I tryed <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and typed `lg` and go to the windows section and here is the output

[image]

here WhatsApp opens as desired (with its own icon in the sidebar) but Github doesn't.

The only difference here is that `app` field for WhatsApp shows the desktop filename while for Github it shows the browser's desktop file name.

So does this mean that a desktop file opening a website will have its separate icon if only if the website is a web app?

Comment: I don’t thing .svg files are supported for this use case, just PNGs that do not exceed 512px on any side. I have not tested non-PNG icons on newer versions of Ubuntu, though … 

Comment: @matigo I think it works, actually, I have also created one .destkop for WhatsApp which works perfectly fine with a separate icon in the sidebar

Comment: You will need to see if you can start Brave with a different window class. If you then also specify that windowclass in your .desktop launcher, it will appear as a separate icon.

Comment: @vanadium you mean `startupVMClass` like this https://askubuntu.com/a/1113914/1112104 ?

Comment: thanks found the way

Answer (score 4):

This method is applicable on creating only 1 .desktop file

I changed my Github.desktop file and added

```
StartupWMClass=Brave-browser
```

if you are using chrome then add `Google-chrome` instead

Next copy the default .desktop file for the browser to `~/.local/applications`

```
cp /usr/share/applications/brave-browser.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/brave-browser.desktop
```

then open the copied .desktop file

```
gedit ~/.local/share/applications/brave-browser.desktop
```

and add this below the `name` field

```
StartupWMClass=brave-browser
```

in the case of chrome add `google-chrome` instead

At the end restart your gnome-session using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and typing 'r' followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>

---

**Result**

A separate icon for github

[image]

[image]

Comment: Nice, worked for me (Ubuntu 22.04) to create a Slack app:
```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Name=Slack Web
Exec=/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome --profile-directory=Default --app=https://app.slack.com/client/<FULL PATH TO MY WORKSPACE>
Icon=/usr/share/icons/slack/slack.png
StartupWMClass=Google-chrome
```