# What is "Open a New Windows with temporary profile" option in Chromium?

Tags: chromium, browser

What is "Open a New Windows with temporary profile" option in Chromium?

What is difference between "Open a New Windows with temporary profile" and "Open a New Windows in incognito mode" ?

I am using `Version 77.0.3865.90 (Official Build) snap (64-bit)` Chromium

[Screenshot of Chromium Dock Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GrWbE.png)

Answer (score 1):

It opens a fresh instance of Chromium with no cookies or customized settings associated with established profiles. See [How to start fresh Chromium instance?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/304293/how-to-start-fresh-chromium-instance).